# What is wrong with my ros installation

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have just installed the ros indigo system followed the sdk.rethinkrobotics.wiki tutorial on my laptop.
However every time I type in the terminal with rosrun or roscore or other command, the response are command not found.
The ros installed on a desktop followed by the same installation tutorial will not response like that.
So I would like to ask what is wrong with my installation or my laptop.*

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/216487/what-is-wrong-with-my-ros-installation/) by [riddick](https://answers.ros.org/users/23558/riddick/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2015-08-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to source your setup.bash file in your .bashrc file.

Edit `~/.bashrc` file and add `source /home/<user_name>/<catkin_ws>/devel/setup.bash` line to the bottom of the file, then restart your terminal.

---

Originally posted by [Akif](https://answers.ros.org/users/23527/akif/) with karma: 3561 on 2015-08-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [duck-development](https://answers.ros.org/users/22870/duck-development/) on 2015-08-25**:
Do not forget first to source /opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash

To her the basic ros commands

**Comment by [riddick](https://answers.ros.org/users/23558/riddick/) on 2015-08-26**:
Thank you and your answers perfectly solve my problem!